# Filtering a list of JavaBeans with Google Guava

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava

In a Java program, I have a list of beans that I want to filter based on a specific property.

For example, say I have a list of Person, a JavaBean, where Person has many properties, among them 'name'.

I also have a list of names.

Now I want to find all the persons whose name is in the name list.

What is the best way to execute this filter using Google Guava?

So far, I've thought about combining Guava with Apache beanutils, but that doesn't seem elegant.

I've also found a reflection extension library here: http://code.google.com/p/guava-reflection/, but I'm not sure how to use it (there's little documentation).

Any thoughts?

p.s. Can you tell I really miss Python list comprehension?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Do it the old-fashioned way, without Guava.  (Speaking as a Guava developer.)

```
List<Person> filtered = Lists.newArrayList();
for(Person p : allPersons) {
   if(acceptedNames.contains(p.getName())) {
       filtered.add(p);
   }
}
```

You can do this with Guava, but Java isn't Python, and trying to make it into Python is just going to perpetuate awkward and unreadable code.  Guava's functional utilities should be used sparingly, and only when they provide a concrete and measurable benefit to either lines of code or performance.

Comment: The main difference between this solution and mine is that this solution creates a new list containing the filtered persons, while mine creates a view over the original list. Whether one or the other is preferrable depends on the use-case.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the use case -- but I'd say that in 90% of use cases, the readability improvements outweigh the small performance benefits.

Comment: You seem to think the only two areas of compromise are readability and performance. Correctness is far more important than both (supposed) readability and performance. If you do it this way, you not only have to test your predicate logic, but also your filtering logic. You've unnecessarily doubled (at least, because of introduced mutable state) the number of things that can go wrong. Multiply this by how many times you do filtering across a codebase... why would you want to work this way?

Comment: I agree that you should minimize _exposure_ of mutability.  Return an ImmutableList copy of the ArrayList, not the ArrayList itself. But speaking as a code reviewer, I prefer to read this code versus the other code.  The salient parts of the code are easier to identify.  If this code returned an ImmutableList, I'd be satisfied with one or two tests, plus the predicate test.

Comment: This is the official Guava position, mind.  The Guava User Guide (which I wrote) gives more details at http://goo.gl/TCHHz.

I should add the caveat that our position will change 180 degrees with the advent of Java 8 and Project Lambda...although at that point, we'll probably rewrite all the functional parts of the library.  ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually decided to go with Scala. I'll probably take another look at Java when Java 8 comes out.

Comment: I'm confused how that could possibly work (or even compile).  The predicate argument to filter must accept a Person (or a base class/interface of Person).  acceptedNames is presumably a set/list of strings.  Even if it somehow compiled, how would it know that it should check for the name property being in acceptedNames vs some other string (or some other property).

Comment: You...are totally right.  (Though it would compile, weirdly enough.)

Answer (score 23):

```
Iterable<Person> filtered = Iterables.filter(allPersons, new Predicate<Person>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Person p) {
        return acceptedNames.contains(p.getName());
    }
});
```

If your list of names is big, you'd better transform it into a Set (HashSet, preferrably) and call contains on this set, rather than the list, because contains is O(1) for a HashSet, and O(n) for a List.

Comment: What should be transformed into a set is the list of accepted names, not the list of persons. That's what contains is called on. Transforming the list of persons into a set has no added value.

Comment: @Daniel's comment on the other answer provides some context on why this would be preferable in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

Explaining your doubts from the sentence:

> So far, I've thought about combining Guava with Apache beanutils, but
>   that doesn't seem elegant.

Java, despite of being so popular, lacks [first-class function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function#Language_support) support<sup>*</sup>, what is [subject to change in Java 8](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html), where you will be able to do:

```
Iterable <Person> filtered = filter(allPersons, (Person p) -> acceptedNames.contains(p.getName()));
```

With lambdas and it will be elegant.

Until then you have choose between:

- old-school way (like @Louis wrote)
- verbose Guava filter (@JB's answer)
- or other functional Java libraries (@superfav's answer).

I'd also like to add to @Lois's answer that [Guava-way would be to create immutable collection](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained), because [they are better than unmodifiable](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/TenThingsAboutImmutableCollections), which is also described in *Item 15, Minimize mutability* in *Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch<sup>**</sup>:

```
ImmutableList.Builder<Person> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
for (final Person p : allPersons) {
    if (acceptedNames.contains(p.getName())) {
        builder.add(p);
    }
}
ImmutableList<Person> filtered = builder.build();
```

(It's implementation detail that `ImmutableList.Builder` creates temporary `ArrayList` under the hood).

<sub>*: it bothers me much, I came from Python, JavaScript and Perl worlds, [where functions are treated better](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)</sub>

<sub>**: Guava and Bloch are *tightly coupled* in many ways ;)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I can't agree enough with Louis and JB answers. I didn't know guava-reflection, maybe [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures) could be what you are looking for:

```
// set up
Person me = new Person("Favio");
Person luca = new Person("Luca");
Person biagio = new Person("Biagio");
Person celestino = new Person("Celestino");
Collection<Person> meAndMyFriends = asList(me, luca, biagio, celestino);

// magic
Collection<Person> filtered = filter(having(on(Person.class).getName(),
                                            isOneOf("Favio", "Luca")),
                                     meAndMyFriends);

// test
assertThat(filtered, hasItems(me, luca));
assertEquals(2, filtered.size());
```

Or maybe Scala, Clojure or Groovy are what you are looking for...

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as the developer of guava-reflection, I am sorry that I have abandoned this project at such an early stage (I have a day job and a wife & kids :-)). My vision was something like:

```
Iterable<Object> thingsWithNames = 
    Iterables.filter(someData,
                     // this is a Predicate, obviously
                     BeanProperties.hasBeanProperty("name", String.class));
```

The existing code is about 60% there, so if you are interested, contact me and perhaps we can get this finished together.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `LinkedList`(or any other collection which *remove* oprations is not very laborious) in single-threaded application the most efficacious solution is:

```
final Iterator<User> userIterator = users.iterator();
while (userIterator.hasNext()) {
    if (/* your condition for exclusion */) {
        userIterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch ! this wont work as you'll run in concurrent access to the List

Answer (score 0):

With Java8 style you can use stream + filter to achieve your goal.

```
persons.stream()
            .filter(p -> names.contains(p.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java8 you can use Collection.removeIf()

```
List<Person> theList = ...;
theList.removeIf(
    (Person p)->"paul".equals(p.getName())
);
```

This will of course modify the current list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using generics using guava, beanutils to filter any list using requested match

```
/**
 * Filter List
 * 
 * @param inputList
 * @param requestMatch
 * @param invokeMethod
 * @return
 */
public static <T> Iterable<T> predicateFilterList(List<T> inputList, final String requestMatch,
        final String invokeMethod) {
    Predicate<T> filtered = new Predicate<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(T input) {
            boolean ok = false;
            try {
                ok = BeanUtils.getProperty(input, invokeMethod).equalsIgnoreCase(requestMatch);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ok;
        }
    };
    return Iterables.filter(inputList, filtered);
}
```