# How to find specific object in nested lists?

Tags: java, guava

Is there any good possiblity to find objects inside nestet lists? Maybe something from guava that supports the following:

```
class PriceInfo() {
    List<PriceType> types;
}

class PriceType() {
    String value;
}

List<PriceInfo> infos;
```

How can I execute: `SELECT * from infos S WHERE S.types.value := 'TEST'`?
Or even find elements in more nested lists.

Comment: i advice you to do it the old way, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8638195/1029621)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested loops (I deleted my comment since you will need nested loops either way):

```
for(PriceInfo info : infos){
 for(PriceType type : info.types) {
  if(type.value.equals("test") { }
 }
}
```

You might get some exotic syntax sugar going with external libraries, but in the end they'll always resort to looping over every item.

Comment: Maybe better use `"test".equals(type.value)` ?

Comment: @Yegoshin I've heard many people on SO say that.  Why is that the better case?

Comment: @peeskillet, you avoid the NPE in case the second parameter is null.
Because you can't call `equals()` on a null reference.
In this way you have no need in checking `type.value != null` before calling `equals`.

Comment: @YegoshinMaxim: That's only advisable if null is supposed to be a valid input. If null isn't supposed to be allowed there, then throwing an NPE as soon as possible is correct and proper.

Comment: @Yegoshin Maxim: That's called a [Yoda Condition](http://wiert.me/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined) and it's not the nicest thing in the world.