# Testing for value in a list java

Tags: java

I currently have a list of Site objects as my Sites object:

```
List<Site> sites = new LinkedList();
```

Site is made up of:

```
String url;
String id;
Host host;
```

I want to write a method that tests to see if my any of the 'Site' values in site contains the url String or the id String.

I can't use the contains method for this, since I don't care about the host value.

Is there a easier way to do it via Collections besides writing something like:

```
public boolean checkValues(String url, String id) {
    for (Site : this.sites) {
          // Check if the url, id is in the site
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easier way, at least until Java 8, with a lambda expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't any such method in Collections yet. I am not sure if there are any 3rd party solutions.

Alternatively, the following can be done (if usecase permits ofcourse)

```
public class Site {
    String url;
    String id;
    String host;

    boolean contains(String str) {
        if(url.contains(str) || id.contains(str)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

=====================

```
for (Site site : sites) {
    if(site.contains(s)) {
//TODO
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Guava collection filter predicate

```
Iterable<Person> filtered = Iterables.filter(allPersons, new Predicate<Person>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Person p) {
        return acceptedNames.contains(p.getName());
    }
});
```

There is same question: [Filtering a list of JavaBeans with Google Guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636502/filtering-a-list-of-javabeans-with-google-guava)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with either Guava, as explained in another answer, or natively within Java 8.  This makes use of a lambda function and a `Stream` object.

Suppose we only care about IDs that contain the string 4 or URLs that contain the string 6.  Here's one approach to that.

This is the more verbose approach, combining Java 8 lambdas and old-school iteration.

```
final Stream<Site> filter =
        siteList.stream().filter(site -> site.getId().contains("4") || site.getUrl().contains("6"));
for(Iterator<Site> filterIter = filter.iterator(); filterIter.hasNext(); ) {
    Site next = filterIter.next();
    System.out.println(next);
}
```

Here's a more succinct way, using the `forEach` `Consumer`:

```
siteList.stream().filter(
    site -> site.getId().contains("4") ||
    site.getUrl().contains("6")).forEach((site) -> System.out.println(site));
```

Here's the most terse approach, using the `System.out::println` method reference.

```
siteList.stream().filter(
        site -> site.getId().contains("4") ||
                site.getUrl().contains("6"))
                 .forEach(System.out::println);
```