# How to use FilterOperator in a List

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to get the entities that have an ID inside of a List of ID. So for example:

```
class A{
    String name;
    List<String> IDs = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

My query does:

```
List<String> etiqueta = new ArrayList<String>();
etiqueta.add(OneID);

Filter filtro = new FilterPredicate("IDs", FilterOperator.IN , etiqueta);
```

I am getting nothing and I don't know how to manage this case.

Could anyone help me?

Diego

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering a list of JavaBeans with Google Guava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636502/filtering-a-list-of-javabeans-with-google-guava)

Comment: Hi, it's not the same... Here you have a snippet of my code: Query query = new Query("Expediente");
  List<String> etiqueta = new ArrayList<String>();
  etiqueta.add(idEtiqueta);
  
  Filter filtro = new FilterPredicate("idEtiquetas", FilterOperator.IN , etiqueta);
  
  query.setFilter(filtro);
  query.setKeysOnly();
  
  PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);
  int count = pq.countEntities(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());