# Find indexs in a List containing a string

Tags: java, string, list

I have a List that contains many URLs. Many of those URLs contain the string "recap". I need to grab every index that contains that specific string. How can I go about this?

Comment: post some code on what you have done so far please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not provide any code, so look at this example and rewrite it for your own ;-)

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

// ...

final List<String> urls = Arrays.asList("foorecap", "recapfoo", "bar", "baz");
final List<String> recaps = urls.stream()
                                .filter(url -> url.contains("recap"))
                                .collect(toList());
```

Comment: This assumes Java 8, which is slick.  So if you have the option, go for this.

Comment: @Chasmo Just a friendly point, the OP asks for index not the item, but I can give you right cuz the question is not CLEAR at all. But I love your way

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for(String url : urls) {
    int index = url.indexOf("recap");
    if(index != -1) {   // found
        System.out.println("index: " + index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava:

```
Iterable<String> passedUrls = Iterables.filter(urls, new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(String url) {
        return url.contains("recap");
    }
});
```

That's a slightly modified version of the solution to another problem which I have not compiled: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636536/857994, but I think it should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

Looping is pretty straight forward:

```
List<String> urls = //your list of String URLS
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
    if(urls.get(i).contains("recap")) {
        indexes.add(i);
    }
}
```