# Using predicate to filter a list

Tags: java, guava, predicate

I have two array lists of objects, how can i use guava's filter to filter out that only the title of each object equal to each other? Each object has a `getTitle()` method.

```
List<Foo> listA;
List<Bar> listB;
for (Foo item: listA)
{
   Iterables.filter(listB, new Predicate()
   {
     //predicate here
   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636502/filtering-a-list-of-javabeans-with-google-guava

Comment: Take a look in the caveats section of [this link](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) and see if your case perhaps falls under that.

Answer (score 0):

Using guava it can be done like this (without checking for null, and optimising on empty collection):

```
// If any of the arrays empty or null, you can return straight away
Set<String> titlesB = new HashSet<String>(Collections2.transform(listB, (b) -> b.getTitle()));
Set<String> titlesA = new HashSet<String>(Collections2.transform(listA, (a) -> a.getTitle()));

// You can further optimize checking the smallest collection (contains is O(1) operation on Set)
Set<String> titlesIntersection = Collections2.filter(titlesB, (b) -> titlesA.contains(b));

List<Foo> commonA = Collections2.filter(listA, (a) -> titlesIntersection.contains(a.getTitle()));
List<Foo> commonB = Collections2.filter(listB, (b) -> titlesIntersection.contains(b.getTitle()));
```

There is also, apache commons intersection function

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html

But you would need to use some additional step there anyway.